# Window onbeforeunload not firing, external JS

Tags: javascript, logging, ecmascript-6, window, onbeforeunload

THE HTML

```
<html>
    <script src="track.js"></script>
</html>
```

track.js:

```
log = "foo=foo&bar=bar";
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {

  send_by_ajax("log.php", "log");
});
```

Attempted:

most outdated JS answers on stack overflow

window.onunload

Didn't Work:

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/analytics", JSON.stringify(analyticsData));
};
```

Browser used:

- Chromium
- Mozilla

Comment: How do you know the script is not working?

Comment: left a 
    console.log(" onbeforeunload detected");

 inside and refreshed the page rapidly, could see it not detected.

Comment: Have you set the console to keep the previous loggings? I'm using the latter within my authetication system, and it works very reliably (sync XHR as a fallback for IE).

Comment: okay just did that

Comment: having preserved the logs, it doesn't trigger the function. I also checked the database and there is no new input.

Comment: Both should work, providing nothing asynchronous is executed. Because the events are not cancelable, any asynchronus call (including AJAX) will be aborted. Make sure you're not testing on a cached page ...

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was something to do with my script